# RegEx lazy quantifier at beginning

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

Why doesn't this

```
re.search(r"\w??at", "cat")
```

match only "at"? Given the `?` quantifier is set to lazy?

Actual result:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='cat'>
```

Expected result:

```
<re.Match object; span=(1, 3), match='at'>
```

Comment: It does not matter if it is lazy or greedy, it matches 0 or 1 time, and since the regex engine parses the string from left to right, `\w?at` = `\w??at`

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is use a **look-behind**. not a lazy quantifier.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you need, if a whole word `at`, then use word boundaries, `r"\bat\b"`